# How to use a non-fixed height with transitions on an accordion

Tags: html, css, transition

My work so far is [here - http://jsfiddle.net/WDz6R/](http://jsfiddle.net/WDz6R/).

I'm trying to make each section of the accordion have an automatic height, but when i use 'height:auto' or a percentage instead of a pixel based height the sections are the correct height, but the transitions break.

Does a fixed height have to be used in order to use css transitions or is there another workaround?

This is the relevant part of the css:

```
#accordion section {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:220px;
}
#accordion section, #accordion .pointer, #accordion h1, #accordion p {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You can't transition to `auto` height. You might want to look into JQuery UI accordion which has this functionality.

Comment: plz check: http://jsfiddle.net/3WK9Y/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, to animate it you need fixed heights. There's a sloppy `max-height` workaround shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDz6R/3/

```
#accordion section.ac_hidden {
  max-height:44px;
}

#accordion section {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:auto;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

Or use jQuery's `slideUp()` / `slideDown()`

Comment: Thank you. I will look in to jQuery's slideUp () / slideDown () for future use.